# JQuery append new div to its parent

Tags: jquery, html, append, appendchild

I have following div tag with child tags.

```
<div class="span6">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I wanna append child `<div class="control-group"></div>` to parent `<div class="span6"></div>` according to the array. So I have written the javascript is as below.

```
$.each(categories, function (k, elem) {
    var options = '';
    var options = '
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="StockCategory">Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="input-xlarge get-category">
    ';
    options +='<option value="">Select Category</option>';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
    });
    options +='
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>';
    $("div.span6").append(options);
}
```

So I wanted to append these child divs according to array but Its not happening. So I needed the following result.

```
<div class="span6">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Item Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name here...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to get it. The work is more appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand...`So I needed the following result.`...and i don't see anything with `StockCategory` and so on... are you saying u just need to clone the first div ... seeing you result looks like that is what u want...

Comment: and where is your `data` for the second each loop ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below jquery will do the needful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var data = { val1 : 'text1', val2 : 'text2', val3 : 'text3' };
    var options = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

/*  options = '<div class="control-group"><label for="StockCategory">Category</label><div class="controls"><select class="input-xlarge get-category">';
    options += '<option value="">Select Category</option>';
    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
    options +='</select></div></div>';
*/  


    options = '<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="' + key + '">' + key + '</label><div class="controls">';
    options +='<input type="text" id="' + key + '" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="' + value + '">';
    options +='</div></div>';



    $("div.span6").append(options);

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would look at is that span6 is missing a closing `</div>` - does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the append code outside the $.each

```
var options = '';        
$.each(categories, function (k, elem) {
var options = '
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="StockCategory">Category</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="input-xlarge get-category">
            ';
            options +='<option value="">Select Category</option>';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            options +='
        </select>
    </div>
</div>';

}
$("div.span6").append(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change your script as

```
var options = '';

$.each(categories, function (k, elem) {
    options += '
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="StockCategory">Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="input-xlarge get-category">
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
    ';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
    });
    options +='
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>';
}

$("div.span6").append(options);
```